# Import java app into android project in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building an android app which has a dependency that i have written as a standalone app in java. I want to import the java project into my android app, not just as a jar file because I may need to make changes to it down the line. is there an easy way to do this in Android Studio?

Comment: As long as you are willing to make it a Gradle project, then yes, it's relatively easy

Comment: I've used gradle for the java app build yes

Comment: Have you any steps for how to go about this?

Comment: If the Java project is already a Gradle project, then right click on the Android project, and use the option that says something like "new module" followed by "from existing sources"

Answer (score 0):

You should move the classes or methods your app is depending on in a library. Both your Java and Android app would have the same dependency on this library.